# How are user logins from a desktop application usually handled?

Tags: http, authentication, desktop-application

What is the common(best practice) way of allowing a user to sign in from a Windows desktop application. Some examples of what I mean are Dropbox or Google Picasa. You sign in with your credentials and then the software is permanently signed in.

I assume the communication takes place over HTTPS. Does the client store the credentials to be sent with requests or is there some sort of token generated? Can anyone point me to some resources on how this should be handled?

Answer (score 0):

Logging into a website normally creates a session at the server. The server then has to identify subsequent requests by the session. Typically, there is one of the following two solutions applied:

1. Session cookie, storing a session identifier
2. URL rewriting, where the session identifier is appended to every link in the html source

Which approach is taken is site dependent, so if you are writing a general 'for all sites' client, you might have to implement both.

In the former case, your application will have to handle the session cookies, in the second case, your application has either nothing to do - if it caches the html response - or will have to emulate the url rewriting itself.

In both cases be aware that the session will expire at server side after a certain period without any activity, so you might be required to generate such.